# Fechar socket PHP com telnet

Tags: php, socket

Estou tentando fechar um *socket* se digitar "sair" através do *telnet* mas a variável `$msg` sempre está vazia dentro do `if`

```
<?php

  $host = '127.0.0.1';
  $port = 10000;

  $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
  echo "socket_create" . PHP_EOL;

  socket_bind($socket, $host, $port);
  echo "socket_bind" . PHP_EOL;

  socket_listen($socket);
  echo "socket_listen" . PHP_EOL;

  $msgsocket = socket_accept($socket);
  echo "socket_accept" . PHP_EOL;

  do {

    $msg = socket_read($msgsocket, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ);

    if ($msg == "sair") {
      break;
    }

    $msg = "Server: " . $msg . "\n";
    socket_write($msgsocket, $msg, strlen($msg));

  } while (true);

  socket_close($socket);
  echo "socket_close" . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sua comparação de strings (`if ($msg == "sair")`) espera exatamente `"sair"` (sem o `\n` no fim).

Altere a seguinte linha:

```
$msg = socket_read($msgsocket, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
```

Para:

```
$msg = trim(socket_read($msgsocket, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ));
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Funcionou. Apenas um detalhe que ele escreve Server: foo e na linha debaixo escreve Server:

Comment: Sim, essa segunda linha que imprime `Server:` "vazia" é o `\n`, e vira uma string vazia depois do `trim`.
Para sumir com ela vc pode checar antes:

    `if (!empty($msg)) socket_write($msgsocket, $msg, strlen($msg));`